# Why does declare -p $ARRAY not show ARRAY's contents?

Tags: arrays, bash, environment-variables

Just messing around with the `bash` and I came up with

```
declare -a K <<< "${SHELL}"; declare -p $K
```

`declare -p` is a short command used to check if an array has been created or not, usually it spits out a declaration for the given array if all goes as expected, if the given variable is in fact an array .

`<<<` redirects the content of *something* to the standard input, this way you can use the content of a variable as if it was coming from the standard input .

`declare -a` declares an array, a *normal* one not an associative one, the keys are just numbers .

So why this command prints out a blob of data that doesn't even looks like the usual output from `declare -p` and it doesn't even look like an array at all . It's just a series of `declare <something> <something>` .

Someone can explain the behaviour of this command ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy are you sure that `declare` doesn't read from `<<<`, if I recall correctly I remember some scripts somewhere using something along the lines of `declare -t <something> <<< varWithMultiLineData` to quickly create an array out of the content of a variable .

Comment: Yes, quite sure. In bash 4.0 or later, `readarray` or `mapfile` could do that; `declare` does not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think I just confused the 2, it was `mapfile` probably, since `readarray` is just an alias for `mapfile` itself apparently . But I still don't get what's going on with this command .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way to use it is:

```
declare -a K=("${SHELL}")

declare -p K
declare -a K='([0]="/bin/bash")'
```

So use `declare -p K` instead of `declare -p $K`

As per `help declare`:

```
  -p    display the attributes and value of each NAME
```

Comment: what does even mean `attributes and value of each NAME` ? What links this `attributes and value` to the `NAME` in question ?

Comment: @user2485710, `-a` -- being an array -- is an attribute. If you had assigned any contents to the array, they would be values.

Comment: That last line is copy/paste of `-p` line from `help declare`. In simple words `declare -p` provides you a text that you can directly use in your script for declaration.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it spits out lines and lines of data that apparently are somehow `attributes and value` of what ? I don't get the logical link between what I see and the array that is supposed to check .

Comment: @user2485710: Please check `help declare` once. It start with `Set variable values and attributes.

    Declare variables and give them attributes.  If no NAMEs are given,
    display the attributes and values of all variables.`

Comment: @anubhava I was reasoning about this under the assumption that the `K` variable was not empty, apparently it's not since the command `declare -p` give the same output of my original command `declare -a K <<< "${SHELL}"; declare -p $K`, weird, but now understand what's going on. Thanks .

Comment: @user2485710, when you use `declare -p $K` instead of `declare -p K`, the `$K` gets expanded and replaced with... nothing, if K's first element is empty. So you're passing it no arguments at all, and literally calling just `declare -p`. Even if `K` were *not* empty, you'd be asking to print the contents of any variable named by the array's first member, and what's the chances of there being a variable by that name?

Comment: @user2485710, ...so, hopefully, by understanding the difference between `declare -p K` and `declare -p $K`, the distinction is less weird.